# Multiple agents arrival based on Variable and database column

Tags: anylogic, agent

In my source block I want to be the amount of agents based on two different factors namely the amount of beds and visitors per bed. The visitors per bed is just a variable (e.g. visitors=3) and the amount of beds is loaded from the database table which is an excel file (see first image). Now I want to code this in the code block as shown in the example in image 2, but I do not know the correct code and do not know if it is even possible.

[image: Database]
[image: Sourceblock]

Comment: Simplest solution is just to do the pre-calcs in the input file and have in the dbase.

Comment: True, but when I want to change the parameters I first need to change the input file again, instead of just changing the variable in anylogic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest solution is just to do the pre-calcs in the input file and have in the dbase.

The more complex solution is to set the Source arrivals as:
[image]

Now, you read your dbase code at the start of the model using SQL (i.e. the [query constructor](https://anylogic.help/anylogic/connectivity/query-builder.html#query-constructor)). Make the necessary computations and create a Dynamic Event for each arrival when you want it to happen, relative to the model start. Each dynamic event then calls the `source.inject(1)` method.

Better still is to not use Source at all but a simple `Enter` block. The dynamic event creates the agent with all relevant properties from your dbase and pushes it into the Enter block using `enter.take(myNewAgent)`

But as I said: this is not trivial

Comment: Thanks @Benjamin, when I compare this with the inputfile  database change it is indeed a lot more complex.

Comment: Only the first time ;)